# I will not ask Unix & Linux to do my homework for me

Tags: discussion

[As per chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47536611#47536611) here is a little tidbit that I made that can be put below [obvious homework questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/480611/90054) where the author is not asking about specific help at where they're stuck but rather want a *Gimme the codez*...

[image: Version 2]

[Version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T2de.png)

If this would not be welcoming enough according to the CoC, please let me know as well. **0:-)**

Comment: How would this help educate the poster on what is and what is not a good quality question for this site? How would it help them understand _why_ we don't want their question? How would it explain what is wrong with the question? How would it help the OP improve the question? It might make someone smile, but that won't be the OP.

Comment: This would be completely inappropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this. This is a wiki, not reddit.

Comment: [No it's not a wiki, and yes: it's part reddit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XNhzr.png) **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @Fabby Whatever you think it is, pasting memes as answers (or comments) is *not* going to make it better; it is an asinine proposal.

Comment: Can't delete the sole comment I left with that as the Q has been deleted in the meantime. I would've thought Bart Simpson would have made at least one person smile, but apparently I just make people frown, which was not the purpose. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯